# How to interact with Java Scanner Class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am super newb with Java and I am trying simple codes with Atom editor (osx). 
Please, someone can help me to understand how can I interact with code with Atom?

I use Script package (Atom) to run the code (cmd+i).

For example if I use the Scanner class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Les {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         String s;
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a string");
         s = in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("You entered string " + s);
    }
}
```

the output will be "enter a string"

Where I can insert the Strings?

Comment: I am not able to understand you question. Where do you want to insert string ?

Answer (score 4):

That is not a final output. It is the first line (`"Enter a string"`) that you printed. Further, you have to type some value *under this message in your console* (I wrote `"hello"`) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After all this, you will see your last message (I got `"You entered string hello"`).

In the console, it will look like

```
Enter a string
hello
You entered string hello
```

Comment: thank you. if I type "hello" + enter in the console (post window) nothing happens

Comment: @sebastiano, share a screenshot with me, please

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about Execution of java classes using Atom Editor, the heading of the question makes it confusing. As you know Atom is an editor for text files. It is a very customizable and hackable editor and people are making packages that extend it to have more IDE-like features such as build and run commands like you're asking for.
If you installed proper scripts on atom for java. After you use the Keystroke for compiling ie., CTRL+i, it should be waiting on the console with string "enter a string" where you can enter here your input.

Personally I recommend you using JCreator or other editor especially made for java, it makes things easier for you.

But if you wanted to understand what happens form the base, then try to use terminal for your code execution until you become familiar and move on to using editors later.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. Probably I need an other package to type in the Atom console. I am reading something about terminal-plus and atom-terminal-panel. Now I am trying from terminal and it works. I will try others ide (editor) like Netbeans, Jcreator is not for osx. thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is the Atom interface where I do not find where type the input for the program.

[image]

Comment: you have to type values 3 times (a string,  an integer and a float) and expand your console window to show the previous outputs and your inputs

Comment: yea as @AndrewTobilko said above after you see the 'Enter a String' you need to input 3 values and hit enter after giving each input, you need to do this because as you are trying to scan three time as shown in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install the platfrmio-ide-terminal from the install packages window.
2. After writing your program toggle on your terminal using ctrl+shift+P
3. Then write- javac "YourPackageName".java
4. Press enter and then write- java "YourPackageName"
5. Press Enter and then you should be able to use the terminal for taking user input for your program.
6. Press enter to execute your code inside the terminal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjW9e.png)